# Angular Creating Dynamic DOM element

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've got a tooltip type popup everytime text is selected. The problem is angular doesn't recognized dynamically added HTML with angular directives unless they're compiled??? I've got code that modifies the DOM in the controller, creates a textbox and then destroys it. Apparently the Angular way is to do such work in a directive. How should I change my code to do the same as it does below except with the DOM manipulation in a directive???

JS

```
argapp.controller("AnnotateCtrl", function($scope) {

$scope.newBox = function( rect ) {

    var div = document.createElement('div');   // make box
    div.setAttribute("class", "shortbox");
    div.setAttribute("ng-controller", "EditCtrl");
    div.setAttribute("ng-mouseover", "hoverside()");
    div.style.border = '2px solid black';      // with outline
    div.style.position = 'fixed';              // fixed positioning = easy mode
    div.style.top = rect.bottom + 5 + 'px';       // set coordinates
    div.style.left = rect.left + 10 + 'px';
    div.style.height =  '25px'; 
    div.style.width = '64px';
            div.innerHTML = "<ng-someOtherthing>"
    document.body.appendChild(div); 

};

$scope.annotate = function() {

    if ( getSelectedText() != "" ) {                        
        killBoxes(); 
        var selection   =   window.getSelection();
        var range       =   selection.getRangeAt(0);
        var rect        =   range.getBoundingClientRect();
        $scope.newBox(rect);
        window.setTimeout( killBoxes, 3000);
    }
};
```

})

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="AnnotateCtrl" ng-mouseup="annotate()" id="tate">
I can be selected.<br>
Lets see how this works.<br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

So in order to do this, you need to use `$compile` and `$link`. It is possible, but it's unnecessary in this case.

Your controller should not be making insertions into the DOM. In this case, you should put your markup on the page, and set `ngShow` to be a variable set by the `ngMouseup`. You don't even need any Javascript for this, actually.

```
<div ng-controller="AnnotateCtrl" ng-mouseup="showPopup = true" id="tate">
I can be selected.<br>
Lets see how this works.<br>
</div>
<div class="shortbox" ... ng-show="showPopup">...</div>
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brandonhorst/8xM6V/).

If you'd prefer to change a class, you can do so using the `ngClass` directive. The power of Angular expressions means that you don't even need to modify the other logic. See the example below:

```
<div class="shortbox" ... ng-class="showPopup ? 'visible' : 'notVisible'">...</div>
```

Comment: The popup div actually needs to popup somewhere near the text. And then disappear or be destroyed a few seconds later as executed by my killBoxes() function.

Comment: That should be done with CSS. You can make it disappear by setting the showPopup variable to false in a `setTimeout` call.

Comment: Wouldn't changing the style in JS still have to be done in some directive since I'm modding the DOM? I don't need it to just work... I already have the functionality working in JQuery... I want to do this in the Angular way.

Comment: Nope - just show and hide it with CSS. I added an example that involves changing the class. In all my experience with angular, I have never seen a time that requires inserting into or removing from the DOM - routing, showing/hiding, or modifying classes has always been enough. Try to step out of the jQuery mindset.